# Initiate image capture using volume button (AVCaptureSession)

Tags: iphone, ios5

Now that this functionality is available in iOS5, is it possible to initiate image capture using one of the volume buttons?

I am using AVFoundation framework for my image capture app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a photo on the volume-up event when using UIImagePickerController with custom camera controls is used and we have set "showsCameraControls" to NO.

Here, the Notification event name was changed for volumeChanged event , @"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification" to @"_UIApplicationVolumeUpButtonDownNotification"

You can find an answer from this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27180527/3759546